# Box 3D JavaFX Rotate

Tags: javafx, 3d, rotation, box, javafx-3d

I have two Boxes (Group), and when I rotate, the image displays like this:

Display Boxes
[image: Display Boxes]

Rotate Boxes
[image: Rotate Boxes]

---

When rotating, the Box (JANELA_MEIO_BOX) is distorted:

```
public class Demo1 extends Application {

private PhongMaterial texturedMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
private Image texture = new Image("/T3D/mapfooter.JPG");
private final PhongMaterial redMaterial = new PhongMaterial();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(final Stage stage) {

    redMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.ORANGE);
    redMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.RED);

    texturedMaterial.setDiffuseMap(texture);
    javafx.scene.shape.Box JANELA_MEIO_BOX = new javafx.scene.shape.Box();

    /*  rotate  */
    JANELA_MEIO_BOX.setWidth(600.0); 
    JANELA_MEIO_BOX.setHeight(340.0);
    JANELA_MEIO_BOX.setDepth(100.0);
    JANELA_MEIO_BOX.setMaterial(texturedMaterial);

    Group JANELA_001 = new Group();

    stage.setTitle("Cube");

    final CameraView cameraView = new CameraView();


    final Scene scene = new Scene(cameraView, 1000, 800, true);
     scene.setFill(new RadialGradient(225, 0.85, 300, 300, 500, false,
            CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop[]{new Stop(0f, Color.BLUE),
                new Stop(1f, Color.LIGHTBLUE)}));
    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    scene.setCamera(camera);
    scene.setOnScroll((final ScrollEvent e) -> {
        camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ() + e.getDeltaY());
    });


    javafx.scene.shape.Box JAN_MAIN = new javafx.scene.shape.Box();
    JAN_MAIN.setMaterial(redMaterial);
    JAN_MAIN.setWidth(1000.0);
    JAN_MAIN.setHeight(600.0);
    JAN_MAIN.setDepth(100.0);

     JAN_MAIN.getTransforms().add(new Translate(1, 1, 1));


    JANELA_MEIO_BOX.getTransforms().add(new Translate(1, 1, 1));

    JANELA_001.getChildren().addAll(JAN_MAIN, JANELA_MEIO_BOX);

    cameraView.add(JANELA_001);

            /*  mouse events */


    cameraView.frameCam(stage, scene);
     MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler(scene, cameraView);
    KeyHandler keyHandler = new KeyHandler(stage, scene, cameraView);
    /*  scene */

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

When rotating, the Box (JANELA_MEIO_BOX) is distorted

Comment: ps: The rows (Box) after rotate are not visible !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two boxes: a 1000x600x100 cube, and a 600x340x100 cube.

When you put both of them in a group, they are placed in the center: the bigger one goes from -500 to 500 in X, -300 to 300 in Y, -50 to 50 in Z, and the same goes for the smaller one, also in Z from -50 to 50.

When you render two shapes with their faces in the same exact Z coordinate you will always get these artifacts.

[image: artifacts]

One quick solution, if you want to see both shapes, is just making the smaller one a little bit deeper:

```
JANELA_MEIO_BOX.setDepth(100.1);
```

[image: no artifacts]

And it is also convenient that you set Scene Antialiasing to Balanced:

```
final Scene scene = new Scene(cameraView, 1000, 800, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
```

Comment: Thank you, José Pereda! Perfect ! Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be good if you mark the question as accepted, so it can be of any help for others as well.

Comment: Okay, José Pereda.  Done ! Thanks !